# Replace all non alphanumeric characters, new lines, and multiple white space with one space

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, alphanumeric

I'm looking for a neat regex solution to replace

- All non alphanumeric characters
- All newlines
- All multiple instances of white space

With a single space

---

For those playing at home (**the following does work**)

```
text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi, " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

My thinking is *regex* is probably powerful enough to achieve this in one statement. The components I think I'd need are

- `[^a-z0-9]` - to remove non alphanumeric characters
- `\s+` - match any collections of spaces
- `\r?\n|\r` - match all new line
- `/gmi` - global, multi-line, case insensitive

However, I can't seem to style the regex in the right way (**the following doesn't work**)

```
text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]|\s+|\r?\n|\r/gmi, " ");
```

---

**Input**

```
234&^%,Me,2 2013 1080p x264 5 1 BluRay
S01(*&asd 05
S1E5
1x05
1x5
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
234 Me 2 2013 1080p x264 5 1 BluRay S01 asd 05 S1E5 1x05 1x5
```

Comment: How exactly does your attempt not work? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Be aware, that `\W` [leaves the underscore](http://regex101.com/r/cW8jA6/2). A short equivalent for `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` would be `[\W_]`

```
text.replace(/[\W_]+/g," ");
```

`\W` is the negation of [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` word characters  (including the underscore)

[Example at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pS6vH1/1)

Comment: Check it and test it, have not much experience in js-regex yet :p Happy you like it

Comment: Note that `\W` will also recognize non-Latin characters as non-word chars.

Comment: I marked this answer correct after all these years, because i looked back and the accepted didn't exclude underscores

Answer (score 150):

Jonny 5 beat me to it. I was going to suggest using the `\W+` without the `\s` as in    `text.replace(/\W+/g, " ")`. This covers white space as well.

Comment: Thanks @T-CatSan for pointing that out! Upped it, and Saruman, you're free to change best answer to whatever :-) But it should be `\W+`, not `[W+]` Well, happy new year all!

Comment: Thanks, @Jonny5! I've made the change you suggested. I had tested with the brackets before and now I see it works without them. Happy New Year to you, too.

Comment: hey @T-CatSan is there a way to add exceptions? I want to keep characters `&` and `-`. Any tips?

Comment: I made the following change /(\W+)|(_)/g to ignore _ also. But just wondering why it is not ignoring in the first model and is my regex is the efficient one.

Answer (score 19):

Since `[^a-z0-9]` character class contains all that is not alnum, it contains white characters too!

```
 text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, " ");
```

Comment: nice and working

Answer (score 8):

Well I think you just need to add a quantifier to each pattern. Also the carriage-return thing is a little funny:

```
text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+|\s+/gmi, " ");
```

*edit* The `\s` thing matches `\r` and `\n` too.

Comment: Yeah there was some tom foolery in there gleaned from other answers on the topic, however that works great thanks!

Answer (score 7):

When Unicode comes to play use

```js
text.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu," ");
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\p{L}\p{N}]+           Any character except Unicode letters and digits
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
```

**JavaScript code snippet**:

```js
const text = `234&^%,Me,2 2013 1080p x264 5 1 BluRąy
S01(*&aśd 05
S1E5
1x05
1x5`
console.log(text.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu, ` `))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

Please be aware, the browser landscape changes rapidly, these benchmarks would be woefully out of date, and likely misleading at the time you reading this.

---

This is an old post of mine, the other answers are good for the most part. However I decided to benchmark each solution and another obvious one (just for fun). I wondered if there was a difference between the regex patterns on different browsers with different sized strings.

So basically I used [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) on

- Testing in Chrome 65.0.3325 / Windows 10 0.0.0
- Testing in Edge 16.16299.0 / Windows 10 0.0.0

The regex patterns I tested were

- `/[\W_]+/g`
- `/[^a-z0-9]+/gi`
- `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g`

I loaded them up with a string length of random characters

- length 5000
- length 1000
- length 200

Example javascript I used `var newstr = str.replace(/[\W_]+/g," ");`

Each run consisted of 50 or more sample on each regex, and i run them 5 times on each browser.

Lets race our horses!

**Results**

```
                                Chrome                  Edge
Chars   Pattern                 Ops/Sec     Deviation   Op/Sec      Deviation
------------------------------------------------------------------------
5,000   /[\W_]+/g                19,977.80  1.09         10,820.40  1.32
5,000   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi           19,901.60  1.49         10,902.00  1.20
5,000   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g         19,559.40  1.96         10,916.80  1.13
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,000   /[\W_]+/g                96,239.00  1.65         52,358.80  1.41
1,000   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi           97,584.40  1.18         52,105.00  1.60
1,000   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g         96,965.80  1.10         51,864.60  1.76
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  200   /[\W_]+/g               480,318.60  1.70        261,030.40  1.80
  200   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi          476,177.80  2.01        261,751.60  1.96
  200   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g        486,423.00  0.80        258,774.20  2.15
```

Truth be known, Regex in both browsers (taking into consideration deviation) were nearly indistinguishable, however i think if it run this even more times the results would become a little more clearer (but not by much).

**Theoretical scaling for 1 character**

```
                            Chrome                        Edge
Chars   Pattern             Ops/Sec     Scaled            Op/Sec    Scaled
------------------------------------------------------------------------
5,000   /[\W_]+/g            19,977.80  99,889,000       10,820.40  54,102,000
5,000   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi       19,901.60  99,508,000       10,902.00  54,510,000
5,000   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g     19,559.40  97,797,000       10,916.80  54,584,000
------------------------------------------------------------------------

1,000   /[\W_]+/g            96,239.00  96,239,000       52,358.80  52,358,800
1,000   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi       97,584.40  97,584,400       52,105.00  52,105,000
1,000   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g     96,965.80  96,965,800       51,864.60  51,864,600
------------------------------------------------------------------------

  200   /[\W_]+/g           480,318.60  96,063,720      261,030.40  52,206,080
  200   /[^a-z0-9]+/gi      476,177.80  95,235,560      261,751.60  52,350,320
  200   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g    486,423.00  97,284,600      258,774.20  51,754,840
```

I wouldn't take to much into these results as this is not really a significant differences, all we can really tell is edge is slower :o . Additionally that i was super bored.

Anyway you can run the benchmark for your self.

[**Jsperf Benchmark here**](https://jsperf.com/replace-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-new-lines/1)

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to OP's query.

Answer (score 4):

A saw a different post that also had diacritical marks, which is great

`s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9À-ž\s]/g, "")`

Answer (score 3):

To replace with dashes, do the following:

```
text.replace(/[\W_-]/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still strugging (like me...) after the above more expert replies, this works in Visual Studio 2019:

```
outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\W", "_");
```

Remember to add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const processStirng = (str) => (
    str
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '') // remove all but alpha-numeric and spaces
    .replace(/ +/g, ' '); // remove duplicated spaces
);
processSting(' $ your    string    here #');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value and helps the OP and others understand the logic behind it.