# Regex pattern for Pilcrow (¶) or Partial Differential (∂) character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find find/replace or convert pilcrow / partial differential characters in a string as they currently show as �.

What I thought would work but doesn't:

```js
const value = 'Javascript Regex pattern for Pilcrow (¶) or Partial Differential (∂) character';
const matches = value.match(/\u2029/gmi);
console.log(matches);
```

But returns empty.

To be honest, I'm not even sure how to achieve what I need to do.

Comment: use `u00B6` instead

Comment: `/¶/gmi`? (Although it might be easier to fix the character encoding.)

Comment: matches is null

Comment: What's wrong with `/[¶∂]/gmi`?

Comment: @SeanDelaney [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436290/4092887) could be useful?

Comment: rather than replacing those specifically, could you use something generic to remove everything that isn't in the characters you want to keep? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864893/replace-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-new-lines-and-multiple-white-space-wi

Comment: Also weird the u2022 is not the second char you are looking for

Comment: If it displays as `�` then it's very likely that it isn't properly encoded to begin with. In other words, you won't find ¶ or ∂ because they aren't there.

Comment: They aren't the same character.  (U+2029) is a PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, but ¶ (U+00B6) is the PILCROW SIGN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct Unicode code points are [U+00B6](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b6/index.htm) and [U+2202](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2202/index.htm), not [U+2029](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm). You'll also want to use a [[] character range](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) in your expression:

```js
const value = 'Javascript Regex pattern for Pilcrow (¶) or Partial Differential (∂) character';
const matches = value.match(/[\u00B6\u2202]/gmi);
console.log(matches);
```

Of course, you don't really need \u escapes in the first place:

```js
const value = 'Javascript Regex pattern for Pilcrow (¶) or Partial Differential (∂) character';
const matches = value.match(/[¶∂]/gmi);
console.log(matches);
```

Last but not least, you say:

> they currently show as �.

If that's the case, it's very likely that it isn't properly encoded to begin with. In other words, you won't find `¶` or `∂` because they aren't there. I suggest you address this first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.prototype.codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) to extract the unicode UTF-16 code point and convert it into hex digits sequence.

```js
const toUnicodeCodePointHex = (str) => {
    const codePoint = str.codePointAt(0).toString(16);
    return '\\u' + '0000'.substring(0, 4 - codePoint.length) + codePoint;
};

const value = 'Javascript Regex pattern for Pilcrow (¶) or Partial Differential (∂) character';

const re = new RegExp(['¶', '∂'].map((item) => toUnicodeCodePointHex(item)).join('|'), 'ig');

const matches = value.match(re);
console.log(matches);
```

See this very nice [`article`](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) by Mathias Bynens.

Comment: Bynens' article is a classic and a recommended reading. But all the [characters involved in this question](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD%C2%B6%E2%88%82) have a 2-byte encoding in UTF-16. Could you elaborate on what your code tries to accomplish?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Taking the code point at the first position and escaping, as all String prototype's methods work on UTF-16 strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them by hex or octal value:

```
const matches = value.match(/\u00B6|\u2202/g);
```

Regex for each:

Pilcrow: `\u00B6` or `\xB6` or `\266`

Partial Differential: `\u2202`